Can I use Hamilton-Jacobi equation here?
Suppose the Hamiltonian does not have a second impulse in it:
$$H = \frac{1}{2}(q_1^2+p_1^2)F(q_2, t).$$
Can I use Hamilton-Jacobi equation here or not? I used it as is and got the same answer, as if I integrated the Hamilton system. But for $q_2$, I had to integrate equation from Hamilton system.
Hamilton-Jacobi solution i have:
$\frac{dS_t}{dt} + \frac{1}{2}(q_1^2+(\frac{dS_1}{dq_1})^2)F(q_2, t)=0$
$\alpha_1 = q_1^2+(\frac{dS_1}{dq_1})^2 \implies S_1 = \int{\sqrt{\alpha_1 - q_1^2}dq_1}$
$\frac{dS_t}{dt} = - \frac{1}{2} \alpha_1 F(q_2, t) \implies S_t = -\frac{1}{2}\alpha_1\int{F(q_2, t)dt}$
$S = -\frac{1}{2}\alpha_1\int{F(q_2, t)dt} + \int{\sqrt{\alpha_1 - q_1^2}dq_1}$
$\beta_1 = \frac{dS}{d\alpha_1} = -\frac{1}{2}\int{F(q_2, t)dt} + \frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha_1-q_1^2}}dq_1} \implies q_1 = q_1(\alpha_1, \beta_1, t)$
$\beta_2 = \frac{dS}{d\alpha_2} = 0$
$p_1 = \frac{dS}{dq_1} = \sqrt{\alpha_1 - q_1^2}$
$p_2 = \frac{dS}{dq_2} = -\frac{1}{2}\alpha_1\int{\frac{F(q_2, t)}{dq_2}dt}$
And from $q_2' = \frac{dH}{dp_2} = 0 \implies q_2 = q_{20}$

Could you detail a bit your calculations and specify the function $F$? And to be clear, do you intend to solve exactly the Hamilton-Jacobi equations?

I have added my solution using Hamilton-Jacobi
$F$ is just a function of $q_2$ and $t$ with any possible properties needed for the solution.
With Hamilton-Jacobi the solution is easier, than going straight forward with diff. equation system, but the hamiltonian does not have the $p_2$, so i dont really know, can i use this method or not.

The cononical equations are independent of any meanings like momentum $p$ or position $q$.
What counts is the independence of coordinates wrt. their partial derivatives and the pairings by the Poisson brackets $\{p_i,q_k\}= \delta_{i,k}$.  So your problem has a Hamiltonian with a cyclic momentum $p_2$ with the consequence that $q_2$ is a free constant of motion. You may rename it $p_2$.
The other way is to see $ q_2$ as a free constant parameter. A variable of such a type is one of the center coordinates of the motion in a constant magnetic field: Both interpretations are useful.
